# How can I create an onclick event on an openlayers marker?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers

This is my current code:

```
journey.path[x].marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(journey.path[x].curpoint,journey.path[x].markerIcon);
journey.path[x].marker.events.register('click', journey.path[x].marker, function(){alert('test');});
layer_device_markers.addMarker(journey.path[x].marker);
```

The marker is added to the map but the alert is not initialized.

There are also no errors in the console.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098609/openlayers-event-register-not-registering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
journey.path[x].marker.events.register('mousedown', journey.path[x].marker, function(evt){
   alert('test');
   OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt); 
});
```