# OpenLayers popup not responding to event

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have an OpenLayers map with a marker and a popup that's supposed to appear when I click on the marker. This works fine in IE8 but not in Firefox 3.6. Any ideas why? As far as I can tell the mousedown event is not getting fired since my log message doesn't appear. The map is at http://ndinfo.heroku.com/test.html and the code I use to create the marker and popup is:

```
function addMarker() {
    var map = g_waze_map.map;

    var markers1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers1" );
    g_waze_map.map.addLayer(markers1);
    var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
    var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
    var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png',size,offset);
    var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(34.7934759272249, 32.0835554760902),icon);

 markers1.addMarker(marker);
            marker.events.register('mousedown', marker, function(evt) {
                    console.log('hi');
                    var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(null,
                                       marker.lonlat,
                                       null,
                                       "<div style='background-color:red; width:150;height:100'>hi</div>",

 null,true,null);

                    map.addPopup(popup);

                    OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);

                });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728852/forcing-an-openlayers-markers-layer-to-draw-on-top-and-having-selectable-layers/4814601#4814601). The key was overriding the `activate()` function in `OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature`. I didn't realize having a control before creating the marker would affect the markers in any way, but it turns out that it does.

```
var shapes = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector( "Shapes" );
map.addLayer(shapes);
var modifyControl =  new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(shapes, {
        activate: function() {
            var activated = false;
            if(OpenLayers.Handler.prototype.activate.apply(this, arguments)) {

                this.map.events.on({
                    "removelayer": this.handleMapEvents,
                    "changelayer": this.handleMapEvents,
                    scope: this
                });
                activated = true;
            }
            return activated;
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you add your ModifyFeature Control after the layer, do you still have to override activate()?

Answer (score 1):

I think that `marker` doesn't have any 'mousedown' event associated. But `OpenLayers.Markers` probably has it. Try this:

```
// Create your markers layer
var markerLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers1" );

// do whatever you want, and then...

// Create your marker
var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(
         new OpenLayers.LonLat(34.7934759272249, 32.0835554760902),
         icon);

// Add your recently created marker to your markers layer
markerLayer.addMarker(marker);

// And bind 'mousedown' event to 'markers' layer, not to 'marker' object
markerLayer.events.register('mousedown', markerLayer, function(evt) {
  console.log('hi');
  var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(null,marker.lonlat,null,
              "<div style='background-color:red; width:150;height:100'>hi</div>",
              null,true,null);
    map.addPopup(popup);
    OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);
});
```

Here is a little example: http://jsbin.com/ezeno3 (click on the map to create the mark, and then click on the mark to open a popup).

I hope it helps. Happy codding!

Comment: But the actual code in your example does bind the event to the marker: marker.events.register('mousedown', marker, function(evt) {...}); I tried your idea and it doesn't seem to help so far. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Please guide this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470470/show-pop-up-box-on-google-map-sometime-it-didnt-show-it