# How to use OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature on KML layer below Layer.Markers

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, openlayers, kml

I came across this interesting problem so I thought I might share my solution and see if anyone has anything better to suggest.

**Background**:

An OpenLayers map, with 3 layers: Google (base), a KML layer with polygons, and a Layer.Markers layer with really large icons from Google Charts API.

**What we want to achieve**:

Using a Control.SelectFeature, we want to highlight/select the kml layer when moving the mouse. We are not interested in the Markers layer at all.

**The problem**:

When the mouse is over one of the marker icons, events are not passed to the kml layer below.

**Tried solutions**:

Check this question:
[Forcing an OpenLayers Markers layer to draw on top, and having selectable layers beneath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728852/forcing-an-openlayers-markers-layer-to-draw-on-top-and-having-selectable-layers/)

Both the accepted answer, my comment, and @Fraser's answer. As far as I could tell, @Fraser's answer didn't have the slighest effect on the problem. A combination of @Ringdahl's answer and application of "pointer-events: none" seemed to solve the problem...for everything except Internet Explorer (no surprise there).

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up implementing to solve the Internet Explorer problem is this.

(If IE)Replace all images of the Marker layer with svg. This allows IE to recognize "pointer-events:none", and events pass through to the layer below. However, when the map changes zoom, the OpenLayers library expects to find the images (something with their position I believe), so the library crashes and the map doesn't zoom.

So, attach a handler to the "movestart" event, restore the original OpenLayers images, and when the map stops moving (after a brief timeout), replace again the images with svg.

As you can imagine, this is pretty-cpu intensive. Couldn't come up with a better solution though in the timeframe I had.

The related code follows:

"kmlInit" shows if the kml layer has been loaded

"markers" is the Marker layer

"getInternetExplorerVersion" is a function that returns -1 if non-IE browser found, or the version otherwise.

```
if (getInternetExplorerVersion()>-1){
    map.events.register('movestart',this,function(e){
        if(kmlInit){
            ieSucksRestore();
        }
    });

    map.events.register('moveend',this,function(e){
        if(kmlInit){
            if (ieCrap){
                clearTimeout(ieCrap);
            }
            ieCrap=setTimeout(ieSucks,1000);           //to give time for multiple move/zooms
        }
    });
}

function ieSucks()
{
    if ($(markers.div).find(".olAlphaImg").length>0){

        try{

            $(markers.div).find(".olAlphaImg").replaceWith(function(){
                var css = this.style;
                var src = this.src;
                var elem = $("");
                var width = parseInt(css.width, 10);
                var height = parseInt(css.height, 10)
                var img = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
                var elem = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg');
                elem.setAttributeNS(null,"class",'svgHack');
                elem.setAttributeNS(null,"x",'0');
                elem.setAttributeNS(null,"y",'0');
                elem.setAttributeNS(null,"width",width);
                elem.setAttributeNS(null,"height",height);
                elem.setAttributeNS(null,"pointer-events","none");
                img.setAttributeNS(null,"x",'0');
                img.setAttributeNS(null,"y",'0');
                img.setAttributeNS(null,"width",width);
                img.setAttributeNS(null,"height",height);
                img.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink',"href",src);
                elem.appendChild(img);
                return elem;
            });
        }catch(err){console.log(err.message);}
    }
}

function ieSucksRestore()
{
    if ($(".svgHack").length>0){
        try{
            $(".svgHack").replaceWith(function(){
                var svg=$(this);
                var id = svg.parent()[0].id;
                var img = svg.children()[0];
                var newimg = $("");
                newimg.css('height',img.height+"px");
                newimg.css('width',img.width+"px");
                newimg.css('position','relative');
                newimg.attr("src",img.href.baseVal);
                newimg.attr("class","olAlphaImg");
                newimg.attr("id",id+"_innerImage");
                return newimg;
            });
        }catch(err){console.log(err.message);}
    }

}
```